# Vlookup with Integer Variables

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to do a Vlookup in my code and I have few integer variables. It gives me the error:

> Run-time Error 1004

The code stops in the line of vlookup. All the variables have values. If someone can see where the problem, please let me know.

```
'Employees
empWS.Range("D1:G" & empLR).Copy
With tmpWB.Worksheets(2)
    .Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .Range("$A$1:$D$" & empLR).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=1
    .Range("A2:D" & empLR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    .ShowAllData
    empLR = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    .Columns(1).Delete
    .Range("D1").Value = "start date"
    .Range("D2:D" & empLR).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],SAP!R1C1:R " & SLRow & " C70, StartColumn,0)" 'it stops here
    .Columns("A:D").AutoFit
End With
```

Comment: Are you saying that `StartColumn` is a variable? Because you are treating it and C70 like a literal string, which isn't going to work.

Comment: Put this on the line before the error and look at what it's trying to use: `MsgBox "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],SAP!R1C1:R " & SLRow & " C70, StartColumn,0)"`

Comment: @braX yes it is a variable, integer type

Comment: @braX How can I use it as a variable in the formula?

Comment: The others who have answered have it correct. Try the things they suggest.

Comment: In other words, you have more than one mistake, and both mistakes need to be corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],SAP!R1C1:R " & SLRow & " C70," &  StartColumn & ",0)"`

You need to put startcolumn outside the speech marks

EDIT

"=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],SAP!R1C1:R" & SLRow & " C70," &  StartColumn & ",0)"

(Patrick Honorez spotted that there was an extra space after R in the first bit)

Comment: Remove the space before the C70

Comment: `"=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],SAP!R1C1:R" & SLRow & "C70," & StartColumn & ",0)"`

Comment: works well thank you both, it was rhe damn space @braX

Answer (score 1):

Try removing extra spaces:

```
.Range("D2:D" & empLR).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],SAP!R1C1:R" & SLRow & "C70, StartColumn,0)"
```

*Space* in a `range` address is an intersection operator.

Comment: StartColumn returns nothing in this form - instead of returning an integer.